# Ruby Marshal updating saved values

Tags: ruby, save, marshalling

I have a text adventure in Ruby, and I need to add the ability to save the game. Well I already added that but it's a huge hack and I'm not happy with how it works. I'd like to use Marshal. I made a very brief version of some of my classes to show you how I attempted to save my game with Marshal. Here is the basic concept of what I tried:

```
SAVE_FILE = "data"

class Player
    attr_accessor :current_room

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @inventory = []
        @current_room = nil
    end
end

class Item
    attr_accessor :some_attribute

    def initialize(name, some_attribute = false)
        @name = name
        @some_attribute = some_attribute
    end
end

class Room
    attr_accessor :people

    def initialize(name, items, paths, people)
        @name = name
        @items = items
        @paths = paths
        @people = people
    end
end

class Person
    attr_accessor :items

    def initialize(name, items)
        @name = name
        @items = items
    end
end

player = rooms = nil

if File.file?(SAVE_FILE)
    # load game from the previous time
    File.open(SAVE_FILE) do |file|
        data = Marshal.load(file)
        player = data[:player]
        rooms = data[:rooms]
    end
else
    player = Player.new("Me")
    rooms = {
        castle: Room.new("Castle", [Item.new("pear"), Item.new("peach")], {n: :hallway, s: :forest}, []),
        forest: Room.new("Forest", [Item.new("sticks")], {n: :castle},
            [Person.new("Elf", [Item.new("Scroll")]
        )])
    }
    # init game
    player.current_room = rooms[:castle]

    # player does some stuff
    rooms[:forest].people[0].items[0].some_attribute = true

    data = {player: player, rooms: rooms}
    File.open(SAVE_FILE, 'w') do |file|
        Marshal.dump(data, file)
    end
end

p player
puts
rooms.each { |_, v| p v; puts }
```

Now this worked really well, unless the code is changed.

If I change rooms to look like this:

```
rooms = {
    castle: Room.new("Castle", [Item.new("pear"), Item.new("peach"), Item.new("Guava")], {n: :hallway, s: :forest}, []),
    forest: Room.new("Forest", [Item.new("sticks")], {n: :castle, s: other_room},
        [Person.new("Elf", [Item.new("Scroll"), Item.new("This doesn't get added in"), Person.new("This guy doesn't either", [])]
    )])
}
```

And I change the item class to this:

```
class Item
    attr_accessor :some_attribute, :one_more

    def initialize(name, some_attribute = false, one_more = true)
        @name = name
        @some_attribute = some_attribute
        @one_more = one_more
    end
end
```

None of the items have a `@one_more` property, and the guava isn't added, as well as the person named "This doesn't get added in". Also forest's paths property doesn't get the :s added in. I can't think of a simple way to fix this, and the values I want updated, to update, with out overriding what the player has done.

I'm sure I could muster up some awful, ugly, and buggy, code that I'd copy+paste into each class to fix this, but I'd love to know what the best way to fix this would be.

If you want to see the full source code, its here: https://github.com/INOVA-Technology/conquest

## EDIT:

To be clear, I know why this doesn't work. I'm just wonder what the best way would be to make it work.

Comment: Euphemistic said the question is a bit unclear. What I can guess from the above code, after you've changed your data structure, it would be never saved when `SAVE_FILE` does exist. i.e. `Marshall::dump` won't be called. Just erase save file and try again.

Comment: No, it saves it when the file doesn't exist. I'm saying I want to be able to update the new values, with having to erase the save file. That'd defeat the purpose of having a save file.

Comment: I updated the code, and question to be more clear. There are some comments explaining why I put it certain lines there.

Comment: If that's so I'd suggest to not store whole instances but their attributes with `marshall_dump` & `marshall_load` [methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Marshal.html#module-Marshal-label-marshal_dump+and+marshal_load). Don't forget set some sane values for missing attributes from an old save.

Comment: Other common although a bit cumbersome way is to store version number in a data file and handle upgrades with specially crafted code accordingly.

Comment: I tried marshal_load, but the values I didn't want to save with it weren't there at all. So I guess the version specific thing maybe my best option.

Comment: `marshall_dump & marshall_load` do work for me. You may ask another question if you've some specific issue with. Other ways are more robust for sure but use of `Marshall` module is very easy and probably enough for your demands.